# Adding a legend to a plot

Tags: r, plot

How to add a legend to the following code that is located outside the plot area.
Here is a prodicble code:

```
par(pty="s")
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels )
pred2 <- prediction(abs(ROCR.simple$predictions + 
                    rnorm(length(ROCR.simple$predictions), 0, 0.1)), 
            ROCR.simple$labels)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr" )
perf2 <- performance(pred2, "tpr", "fpr")
# Plot pred 1
plot(perf, col="red")
# plot pred 2
plot(perf2, add = TRUE, col="blue")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why should the legend be outside the plot area?  There is a big empty space at the lower right.

Comment: Because the plot changes every time I run my code, the original code. Sometimes, I got curves at the low levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that you can do this is to use `par` to increase the margin at the top and also to enable writing outside the plot region.  Then you can use `legend` with a negative `inset`.

```
## Your graph
par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,6,2.1), xpd=TRUE)
plot(perf, col="red")
plot(perf2, add = TRUE, col="blue")

## Add Legend
legend("topright", c("Pred1", "Pred2"), lty=1, 
    col = c("red", "blue"), bty="n", inset=c(0,-0.15))
```

[image: Legend in margin]