# Plotting functions of functions

Tags: r

So I'm kind of new to R, and I need to plot some functions. My understanding of `curve` in R is that it requires a function that has `x` as its single input. Since my functions are all just different representations of the same main function, I first thought I would create the main function, and then I would define each specific function individually.

```
# The principal function
puiss <- function(theta, inf, sup) {
  for(k in inf:sup) {
    total += (choose(30,k) * (theta^k) * ((1-theta)^(30-k)))
  }
}

# The specific functions I need to draw on the same plot
p1 <- function(x) { puiss(x,2,13) }
p2 <- function(x) { puiss(x,3,14) }
p3 <- function(x) { puiss(x,3,13) }

# Can't even get to trace just a single one... :'(
curve(p1,
0, 1,                              # from 0 to 1
main="puissance(theta)",           # title
xlab="x", ylab="theta")            # axes

curve(p2, add=T)                   # adding the other function
curve(p3, add=T)                   # adding the other function
```

I get this error:

`'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'`

I've tried multiple approaches, but this one seemed to be the closest one to what it should have been.

Among other alternatives, I've tried:

- changing from `<-` to `=` for the specific functions
- using no `{}` (brackets) for the specific functions
- plugging the `for` loop directly into the curve and replacing `theta` by `x` and `inf:sup` appropriately
- trying to use `p1(x)` inside `curve`
- I've also read that some times `Vectorize()` is needed, so I've tried `Vectorize(p1)` inside `curve`

What am I doing wrong?

It might help to disclose that my main function is just a `Binomial(30, theta)`'s mass function (probability) evaluated in different regions (the summation within the boundaries, my sigma which is a `for` loop because I couldn't figure out how to properly create a `sigma` function in `R`). In other words, it is a *cumulative distribution function*.

Ultimately, I'm trying to plot the 3 specific functions together on the same plot.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using some Python (or similar) code in your function definition.
Here is the `R` version of it, which for me will plot the results when calling `curve`.

```
puiss <- function(theta, inf, sup) {
  total = 0
  for(k in inf:sup) {
    # "+=" does not work for R
    total <- total + (choose(30,k) * (theta^k) * ((1-theta)^(30-k)))
  }
  # you need to use parentheses around total
  return(total)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've reverted the question back to its initial state so that your answer makes more sense. Maybe mention the fact that I didn't even have a `return`. That's embarrassing. (However, I was indeed coding in NotePad, which might not have been a good idea.)

Comment: A loop isn't even necessary in R. You can just do `puiss <- function(theta, inf, sup) {k <- inf:sup; sum(choose(30,k) * (theta^k) * ((1-theta)^(30-k)))}`. An explicit `return()` is not required.

Comment: @MrFlick how could I add a legend of the three functions plotted so as to know which is which ? I've added colors, but it still doesn't identify the functions.

Comment: True, I wasn't quite focused on improving the function, but merely on making it work.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to add a legend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186850/adding-a-legend-to-a-plot